# C Block signals

Tags: c, shell, signals

I am trying to write a shell-like application and struggle with the signal blocking. I want to disable/block some signals like SIGINT or SIGQUIT so when user press Ctrl+C or Ctrl+\, nothing will happen.

I have done some research and was able to do that by using either `signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN)` or `sigaction()`.

My problem is that the signal is not totally blocked. When I pressed Ctrl+\ several times inside my application, it will not exit as expected but will also display this `^\`.

Also, because I use an `readline()` to catch the input of the user, when I use Ctrl+\ and press Enter, there is a strange newline.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you blocked signals properly. As you disabled the signal, when you press `Ctrl+\` then your terminal sends it to your application. The same way as `a` is sent when you press "A" on your keyboard, but unlike "A", `Ctrl+\` does not generate any printable character, your terminal can not print it directly. `^\` is basically the special notation of that non-printable character. You will also get that "character" in `readline()` results, that is the strange thing are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there a way to hide that?

Comment: Not sure which one might be the solution for you, but you might try several things. You might try to put `echo-control-characters` to your `inputrc` to instruct readline not to echo control characters. Also, you might try to use `stty -echoctl` to disable echoing for you terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in C language, you can use the following function:

```
#include <termios.h>

void block_signals ()
{
    struct termios old_termios, new_termios;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_termios);
    new_termios = old_termios;

    new_termios.c_cc[VINTR] = 0; // Ctrl+C
    new_termios.c_cc[VSUSP] = 0; // Ctrl+Z

    // Set the new terminal attributes
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_termios);
}
```

I have tested this code in the GNU Linux operating system with GCC and there were no problems.